# Web.config httpRedirect wildcard folder and index.aspx

Tags: redirect, iis

I'm trying to redirect any pages inside */company/* (including the root */company/* itself) to another page.

This is what I got so far:

```
 <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
  <add wildcard="*/company/*" destination="/another/page/" />
</httpRedirect>
```

This works, however it has the side effect of redirecting any other files (images, scripts, etc) that contain */company/* in their path.

I can force it to redirect only *.aspx* files but then it won't redirect the root folder */company/*

```
<add wildcard="*/company/*.aspx" destination="/another/page/" />
```

How can I do this using the **IIS httpRedirect module**?

There are plenty of redirect examples out there using the IIS URL rewrite module but unfortunately I can't install that module on live server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the complete path on wildcard attribute, like this:

```
<add wildcard="your-full-path/company/*" destination="/another/page/" />
```

And append multiple "add" node's for all root folder in wich you need this rule